# Laravel 5 - return view

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, laravel, view

I have run into to a problem with using the view function

The view does exist (check for that in the code) but the content doesn't show up.

im using the view which comes with laravel 'welcome'

```
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        if (view()->exists('welcome')) {
            return view('welcome');
        }else{
            return "Failed";
        }
    });
```

I was wondering if I need to set something up, to get it work

Comment: 1) Is there any error displayed when accessing the view? 2) Where do you store the **welcome** view and what is its extension? 3) Are you sure the `return view(...)` statement is reached in the route?

Comment: 1) no there are no errors, just an empty screen. 2) the view is stored at `resources/views/welcome.blade.php` , and i havn't touched it since i downloaded laravel
3) yes i'm pretty sure, if i echo something before the `return`, it shows.
i'm getting the same result, if only using `return view(...)`

Comment: Check this and verify your debug level: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#configuration. Secondly, use dev tools (F12) of your browser to look for any internal server errors on load (Network tab).

Comment: I checked you code and it works. Does your default install of Laravel work?

Comment: no, it does not, but i have tried to download it a couple times to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have access to this file , you have to give your user privilages to your server . 
You can try chmod 777 -R YourProject to be sure if it is privilage problem or not .

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::delete('/usuario/{ident}', function ($ident) {

DB::table('usuario')->where('ident', $ident)->delete();  


return redirect('/usuarios');

});
```

Well this work  for delete using ident..